# What is the difference between object A extends B and class A extends B and later new B

Tags: scala

In the code I have:

```
object A extends B with Serializable
// ...
A.doSomething()
```

I wanted to change it to:

```
class A extends B with Serializable
// ...
val a = new A()
a.doSomething()
```

but it appears that `a` is not serializable. What can I do to have the  object like `A` but using `class`?

Comment: Your question title says `new B`, and `B` is not `Serializable`. But you have `val a = new A`, which is `Serializable`. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` *is* in fact serializable in your code.  This similar code shows it:

```
import java.io._
class B
class A(val foo: Int) extends B with Serializable
val a = new A(1337)
val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/a"))
oos.writeObject(a)
oos.close
val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/tmp/a"))
val aFromFile = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[A]
aFromFile.foo //1337
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized the problem in my code laid elsewhere.